# Pymongo MongoDB SSL Certificate Expired Error

Tags: python, database, mongodb, ssl, nosql

I am building an application using MongoDB Atlas as the database and Django REST Framework on the backend.

I'm trying to initiate the connection between the two, however, I keep getting this error back:

```
Error connecting to MongoDB: 'ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992),'ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992),'ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992), Timeout: 
30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 63d06b0f8f66929906b7c17a, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription (''ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect(''ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992)')>, <ServerDescription ('ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net, 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect(''ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992)')>, <ServerDescription (''ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992)')>]>
```

I don't understand how this issue is arising as MongoDB Atlas is supposed to deal with issuing the SSL certificate and I've watched multiple videos that appear to be doing the same thing I am. Here is my code:

```
import pymongo

conn_str = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.mongodb.net/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"


# set a 5-second connection timeout
client = pymongo.MongoClient(conn_str)

try:
    print(client.server_info())
except Exception:
    print("Unable to connect to the server.")
```

*I have replaced my actual connection string with a generic one for security so assume that this is correct*

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The SSL certificate of the MongoDB service expired or the date on your machine is set to the future. Check the date! If it is correct contact their service!

Comment: Check with openssl `openssl s_client ag-lfgx9hg-shard-00-02.glqs5bt.mongodb.net:27017`. It should show some more information where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue I followed the steps below as outlined in this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ssl-certificateverifyfailed-while-python-tried-retrieve-sanjeev-kumar

Step 1. Download Pem file from this link https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-r3.pem

Step 2. Rename the file from .pem to .cer

Step 3. And install the cert file to your machine where python program executes.

Step 4. Restart the machine if required and re-run your program.

it will resolved SSL Issues.

Note - a comment on the article said that it did not work for Mac, I cannot confirm this as I use Windows but should be kept in mind for Mac users